# Append data to a google spreadsheets V4

Tags: javascript, fetch, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make a little database with google spreadsheets API V4. I only need a write function in the spreadsheets, just to follow if my users use some functions.

I have followed this [article](https://medium.com/@inaguirre/google-sheets-api-tutorial-with-javascript-588f581aa1d9) and also read the doc from Google.
I have tried to use *batchUpdate* like in the article but I only have an error 400.
I have switched to *append* but I have CORS error even it is running in my localhost or error 401.

```
fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:append',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    Authorization: 'Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]',
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'content-type':'application/json'
                },
                body: {
                    "spreadsheetId": "{spreadsheetId}",
                    "range": "A1:C1",
                    "insertDataOption": "INSERT_ROWS",
                    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
                    "resource": {
                        "range": "A1:C1",
                        "values": [
                        [
                            "1",
                            "2",
                            "3"
                        ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            })
```

I just expect to add a row in my spreadsheets but I have a CORS or 401.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad the issue of your question was resolved. About your new issue, can you post it as new question? Because that is different from your this question. And from your replying, I could know that you have already resolved your issue by yourself. So I think that my answer was not useful for you. So I have to delete my answer. Can you post your answer and accept it? By this, other users who have the same issue can see your question as the resolved issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found, the url was wrong.
Here is the solution :

```
fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}:append?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=RAW',{
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    "Authorization": 'Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]',
    'content-type':'application/json'
  },
  body: {
    "range": "A1:C1",
    "values": [
      [
        "32",
        "33",
        "34"
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

**Warning**
I had tryied to write `[A1:C1]` or `A1:C1` in the URL to replace `{range}`.
It didn't work but with `A1%3AC1` i had no troubles.

Comment: I am using this code in ajax format but it;s not working. can you pls suggest how to make it work for ajax?